# Map data to table

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, html-table

I am trying to map my data stored in  mongodb to a table in React

I have data stored in my database in the following way below in the link below:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1g-kOjw5dp4ailubqPflI9_vuDLW82Awh/view?usp=sharing

I want the data to be mapped in the following way.

[image]

I have managed to bring the column headings dynamically, but I cannot figure out how to map the data to the table for each employee dynamically.

[image]

The code for the to bring the table headings dynamically is given below

```
  <table class="table table-bordered">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col">Employee ID</th>
            {data.map((emp) => {
              return (
                <th scope="col" colspan="4">
                  {emp.Date}
                </th>
              );
            })}
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <th scope="col"></th>
            {data.map((emp) => {
              return (
                <>
                  <th scope="col">Shift In</th>
                  <th scope="col">Shift Out</th>
                  <th scope="col">Actual In</th>
                  <th scope="col">Actual Out</th>
                </>
              );
            })}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
         
        </tbody>
      </table>
```

Please help me fill the data for the columns.

Comment: can you please share the data from response so we can see to map it

Comment: It is exactly the same data which I have mentioned in the drive link sir

Comment: some feature like group headers you can use some library like `react-bootstrap-table-next`

Comment: if you can provide your sample data, I can help you with `react-bootstrap-table-next` code and what the `dynamic` means ?

Comment: as per your doc file data, there's nothing like the name field

Comment: Dynamic means the number of columns here is dynamic, and changes, therefore, the data should also change accordingly

Comment: The drive link data is the sample data I am getting it from the backend